How do i retrieve a list of products by type in liquid
I'm trying to show related products by type, the idea is when someone abandoned browsing, I'd like to trigger an email to the customer to bring them back to the store, the email will contain the main product that the customer last browsed, and below 3 more products that have the same type of product.
I'm thinking something along those lines but its not working:
{% assign abandoned_products = abandoned_visit.products_viewed %}
{% assign abandoned_product = abandoned_products.first %}

{% if abandoned_product %}

<!-- Display the abandoned product -->
<h2>You were looking at:</h2>
<div>
    <a href="{{ abandoned_product.url }}">
        <img src="{{ abandoned_product.featured_image | img_url: 'medium' }}" alt="{{ abandoned_product.title }}">
        <p>{{ abandoned_product.title }}</p>
    </a>
    <p>{{ abandoned_product.price | money }}</p>
</div>

<!-- Fetch and display 3 more products from the same product type -->
{% assign product_type = abandoned_product.type %}
{% assign related_products = all_products | where: 'product_type', product_type | where: 'id', '!=', abandoned_product.id | limit: 3 %}

{% if related_products.size > 0 %}
<h2>You might also like:</h2>
<div>
    {% for product in related_products %}
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin: 10px;">
        <a href="{{ product.url }}">
            <img src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: 'medium' }}" alt="{{ product.title }}">
            <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
        </a>
        <p>{{ product.price | money }}</p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endif %}

{% endif %}


Your Liquid code seems mostly correct for retrieving a list of related products based on the type of an abandoned product. However, there are a few adjustments and additions that can enhance its functionality and reliability:
{% assign abandoned_products = customer.last_order.line_items %}
    {% assign abandoned_product = abandoned_products.first %}
    
    {% if abandoned_product %}
    
    <!-- Display the abandoned product -->
    <h2>You were looking at:</h2>
    <div>
        <a href="{{ abandoned_product.product.url }}">
            <img src="{{ abandoned_product.product.featured_image | img_url: 'medium' }}" alt="{{ abandoned_product.product.title }}">
            <p>{{ abandoned_product.product.title }}</p>
        </a>
        <p>{{ abandoned_product.product.price | money }}</p>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Fetch and display 3 more products from the same product type -->
    {% assign product_type = abandoned_product.product.product_type %}
    {% assign related_products = collections.all.products | where: 'product_type', product_type | where: 'id', '!=', abandoned_product.product.id | limit: 3 %}
    
    {% if related_products.size > 0 %}
    <h2>You might also like:</h2>
    <div>
        {% for product in related_products %}
        <div style="display: inline-block; margin: 10px;">
            <a href="{{ product.url }}">
                <img src="{{ product.featured_image | img_url: 'medium' }}" alt="{{ product.title }}">
                <p>{{ product.title }}</p>
            </a>
            <p>{{ product.price | money }}</p>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
